# Kerberos Sercurity Error

Tags: windows, dns, kerberos

I am having a problem with my server and so far couldn't find any solution for this. When I try to add a server from a server manager (windows server 2012) I can see only the kerberos security error. Both servers are in the same domain(i have tried from several servers from domain and got the same error).

The strange thing is when I unjoin the problematic server from domain and rejoin it with another name it works normally. But the problem is to make it work with existing name. Anyhelp will be highly appreciated
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I've just encountered the same error and hope this solution proves useful to others.

Situation: I had to wipe and reinstall a virtual server on which I'd previously had to set some Service Principal Names, and some SPNs for a service account. Turns out the SPNs were still there for the old server/account and I had to remove them.

I recommend checking for and removing rogue SPNs to resolve this. Use the following commands in an elevated command prompt:

```
setspn -l <servername/username>
```

In my case I had problems with MBAM, the Bitlocker admin tool, so for example I used:

```
setspn -l mbam01
```

Which gave me the output (changed names to protect the innocent):

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=MBAM01,OU=Member Servers,DC=corp,DC=domainname,DC=com:
    termserv/mbam01.corp.domainname.com
    termserv/mbam01
    http/mbam01.corp.domainname.com
    http/mbam01
    HOST/MBAM01
    HOST/mbam01.corp.domainname.com
```

This will list the SPNs associated with the server or user account. Then you remove the errant SPNs with this command:

```
setspn -d <listed service> <servername/username>
```

In my case it turned out the mbamapppool user had http/mbam01 and http/mbam01.corp.domainname.com associated with it, causing Server Manager to fail to poll the server. I removed the http/ refs from the user and then added them to the server with the following commands:

```
setspn -d http/mbam01 corp\mbamapppooluser
setspn -d http/mbam.corp.domainname.com corp\mbamapppooluser
setspn -s http/mbam01 mbam01
setspn -s http/mbam01.corp.domainname.com mbam01
```

I then refreshed Server Manager and it polled the server successfully, and the Kerberos Security Error had gone.